# How to extend the behaviour of components in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I mostly have experience in React and am wondering what the Vue centric way of doing this would be:

I would like extend this component: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form so that `label-position` is `top` on mobile and `left` on desktop. I'm unusure how I would spread the properties passed into the component on to the element.

Here is the pseudo-code I have so far:

```
<template>
  <el-form v-bind="formProps" :label-position="labelPosition">
    <slot />
  </el-form>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.component('el-form-responsive', {
  data() {
    return {
      labelPosition: 'top',
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.mobileQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 720px)');
    this.onMobileQueryTrigger(this.mobileQuery);
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this.onMobileQueryTrigger);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this.onMobileQueryTrigger);
  },
  methods: {
    onMobileQueryTrigger(query) {
      if (query.matches) {
        console.log('is mobile');
        this.$data.labelPosition = 'top';
      } else {
        this.$data.labelPosition = 'left';
        console.log('is not mobile');
      }
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

From what I understand `v-bind` [does not copy over events and directives](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4962#issuecomment-319863783), so this doesn't work:

```
<el-form-responsive
  :formProps="{
    class: 'form',
    ':model': 'formValues',
    'status-icon': true,
    ':rules': 'rules',
    ref: 'form',
    'label-width': 'auto',
    '@submit.native.prevent': 'submitForm'
  }"
>
```

It's also inconvenient and ugly, I would rather just do:

```
<el-form-responsive
  class="form"
  :model="formValues"
  status-icon
  :rules="rules"
  ref="form"
  label-width="auto"
  @submit.native.prevent="submitForm"
>
```

But I'm unsure how to spread these props on to `el-form`? Is this not the Vue centric way to go about this? Seems like a fundamental thing so maybe I have it wrong.

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners. Something like `v-bind="$props" v-on="$listeners". You'd also need to copy across the `props` definition from the other component, or use `$attrs` instead of `$props`. Extending rather than composing may be simpler in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to test this now, but I believe [$attrs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs) and [$listeners](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners) should do what you want to achieve or at least point you in the right direction:

```
<template>
  <el-form v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners" :label-position="labelPosition">
    <slot />
  </el-form>
</template>
```

Comment: Nice one I'm glad that Vue has a built in way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in passing props like below:

```
<el-form v-bind="formProps" label-position=":labelPosition">
    <slot />
</el-form>
```

In the above codes, `label-position=":labelPosition"` is wrong.

It should be`:label-position="labelPosition"`, so;

```
<el-form v-bind="formProps" :label-position="labelPosition">
    <slot />
</el-form>
```

Comment: Thanks will fix but as mentioned it's pseudo code and not the root of the issue